# Open link on press of "sap.m.Button" instead of using "sap.m.Link"

Tags: sapui5

I am relatively new to UI5. My search for "[sapui5] icon link" brought no useful results. So here is my question.

I have the following `sap.m.Link`

```xml
<Link id="myLink" href="http://stackoverflow.com/" text="Stackoverflow" />
```

which displays the text "Stackoverflow" on the UI, and when I click on it, I will navigate to *stackoverflow.com*. That's the effect I want.

But how can I replace the text with an icon, for example `"sap-icon://download"`? According to the Link-API, it doesn't have an attribute `icon`. So is there a way to get the same effect using `sap.m.Button` that *does* have this attribute:

```xml
<Button icon="sap-icon://download" press=".onDataExport" />
```

What would the handler `onDataExport` look like? My idea is to use a (somehow) hidden `sap.m.Link` and a `sap.m.Button` containing the icon. The `press`-handler of the Button would then somehow trigger a 'link clicked' (not sure if that is possible).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SAPUI5 Open Link on Button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66935407/sapui5-open-link-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code in your `onDataExport` function in controller:

```
sap.m.URLHelper.redirect("https://stackoverflow.com/", true);
```

Refer to the below link for info: [ui5.sap.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Link/preview](http://ui5.sap.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Link/preview)

Answer (score 1):

My answer comes a bit late, but I hope that it will help others, as I searched for a ready-to-use Link including an Icon (although this does not seem to be the real need of StoneCrusher).

**Button which triggers link navigation:**

If you want a sap.m.Button to act like a classical  link, then you can attach a press event and use window.open in that event, like:

```
        myButton.attachPress(function () {
            window.open(url,target);
        });
```

**Link with UI5 icon:**

If you want to display a sap-icon in a sap.m.Link, then you have to extend the link, include an aggregation which contains the icon and then render the icon before you render the text of the link.

```
    renderer : function(oRm, oControl) {
        [...]
        oRm.write("<a"); 
        oRm.writeControlData(oControl);  
        oRm.addClass("sapMLnk sapMLnkMaxWidth touconLink");
        oRm.writeClasses();
        oRm.write("href=\"javascript:void(0);\" ");
        oRm.write(">");
        //Render icon
        if (icon!="") {
            oControl.getAggregation("_icon").setIcon(icon);
            oRm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("_icon"));
        } 
        oRm.writeEscaped(text);
        oRm.write("</a>");
    }
```

I was in need of both and published these and other custom UI5 convenience controls here: [www.toucon.fr](http://www.toucon.fr)

Answer (score 0):

sorry only got reply in JSON style, but you see what is missing in your code:

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.IconPool");
var sBack = sap.ui.core.IconPool.getIconURI("nav-back");

var button = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
  icon : sBack,
});
```

Comment: It's not an icon that I miss in the Button control but the Button shall trigger a link navigation.